# Help me to find good references about this equation.

Tags: reference-request, math-history, hypergeometric-function

What are some recommended references disucssing Gauss's Hypergeometric Equation?

Specifically, I would like references discussing:

- the origin of the equation,
- how to obtain it,
- the solution by the method of series.

Comment: You should spend a few hours searching the internet and using your college library.

Answer (score 2):

One of the books that I believe would be helpful for you in this case is "Differential Equations with applications and historical notes" by G.F.Simmons.  The pdf file is available online. Almost everything is there what u asked for. Happy learning. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yesss, thank you so much!!!

Comment: Simmons books are all really good for their historical notes and exposition.